# How to sense the amplitude of mic while recording with audiorecord in android?

Tags: android, microphone

i am recording the sound with audiorecord in android and at the same time i want to get notified about the amplitude of the input voice  I want to send peak values at interval of times as input to my service . Is it possible .  Also wanted to know how to get notified when audio file is finished while playing the media file with audiotrack.

the link that i am working is

http://androidgenuine.com/?tag=sound-record-android-modify-voice-on-android